# Is it possible for an anchor link stay highlighted on single page website using pure css?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to keep an anchor link highlighted on a single page using pure CSS?

I already saw a lot of tutorials about the link highlight when someone is in a designated page. But I never saw someone do what I asked... only with javascript. But I don't wanna use js because is a fancy noscript page that I want to do.

```css
ul {
    margin: auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding:0px;
    position:fixed;
}

a {
    width:30px;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-color:gray;
    color:#ffffff;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color:black;
}
.contentWrap {
    top:0px;
    width:300px;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#FF9933;
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.container {
    height:1000px;
}
#one {
    background-color:orange;
}
#two {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
</ul>

<!-Content/->
<div class='contentWrap'>
    <div class='container' id='one'></div>
    <div class='container' id='two'></div>
</div>
<!-Content/->
```

Comment: What do you mean by “keep highlighted”? Do you want the background to stay black even after the mouse leaves the link?

Comment: yes! I want the background of the anchor stay highlighted when the user is seeing the designated #content without using javascript - just css... sorry about my code was in hurry...

Comment: No, the only way will be using JS. CSS has `:active` and :`focus` states, but I don't think any of them gives you what you want.

Comment: :( what if I use some input && button or whatever...?!!? I will try to work this out...

Comment: I tried by using radio buttons before each anchor, but linking the label to the radio button by a `<label><a>Text</a></label>` disables the link, and `<a><label>Text</label></a>` disables the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using only css with the [`:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) and the general [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors). However, the links must come after the containers and the containers can not be in another element.

For the html, you need to remove the `.contentWrap` div and move the `<ul>` after the `.container` divs.

```html
<div class='container' id='one'></div>
<div class='container' id='two'></div>

<ul>
    <li><a href='#one'>One</a></li>
    <li><a href='#two'>Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

For the css, you need to change the `ul` and `.container` rules. In the selector for the new rule, `:target` selects the container with the `id` that the fragment identifier links to. Then `~` selects the following `ul` with the descendant `a` with the corresponding  `href` attribute.

```
ul {
    margin: auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding:0px;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container {
    height:1000px;
    width:300px;
    margin: auto;
}

#one:target ~ ul [href='#one'],
#two:target ~ ul [href='#two'] {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```css
ul {
    margin: auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding:0px;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

a {
    width:30px;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-color:gray;
    color:#ffffff;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color:black;
}

.container {
    height:1000px;
    width:300px;
    margin: auto;
}
#one {
    background-color:orange;
}
#two {
    background-color:green;
}

#one:target ~ ul [href='#one'],
#two:target ~ ul [href='#two'] {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' id='one'></div>
<div class='container' id='two'></div>

<ul>
    <li><a href='#one'>One</a></li>
    <li><a href='#two'>Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you use my code above to show that... because is not working for me... :(

Comment: @user4779475 Added a code snippet based on your example.